# ¿Declaración fuera de alcance por mala estructura del programa?

Tags: javascript

Bueno empiezo diciendo que estaba haciendo un juego, no soy muy conocedor de la estructura de este tipo de proyectos asi que intenté lo que puede

main.js

```js
let width = screen.width;
let heigth = screen.height;

function Main(){
  PreRender()
}

addEventListener("resize", () => {
  width = screen.width;
  height = screen.height;
  
})
```

Como pueden ver tengo un archivo main que aprovecho para adaptar la pantalla del Canvas

game.js

```js
let app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 640, height: 360 });
  document.body.appendChild(app.view);


function PreRender(){

}
```

Mi idea en la función Game.js fue utlizar dos funciones una llamada PreRender dónde cargama los exprites y otras tareas antes del renderizado y otra Render

Pero me tope con un problema, la variable app no puede ser local ya que el evento rezise debe poder modificar el valor de app para cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla

Mi segunda pregunta seria ¿Que tipo de estructura deberia utilizar en mi programa?

Este tipo de estructura que hice usando funciones la veo como muy debil y con algunos cuellos de botella me gustaría que me digan que estructura debería utilizar en el programa

Answer (score 1):

Puedes importar y exportar variables, en este caso al final de tu `game.js` agrega `export { app };` mientras que en `main.js` lo importas como `import { app } from './game.js';`